# How to handle ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https, ssl-certificate

I'm doing simple GET request to my URL and I get the error "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE". THis is fine, as certificate is self-signed. But I have two questions regarding it:

1. Is there a way to overcome this in extension? Like setting a flag in request or sth like that? (probably not likely)
2. Is there a way just to handle this error (to notify user)? I've checked all XMLHttpRequest fields and cannot see anything that can indicate this error. Status field has value of 0 (zero).

Any ideas?

Comment: Answers [here](https://superuser.com/q/487748/297822)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. No, the extension API does not offer any method to modify SSL settings or behavior.
2. You could use the [`chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onErrorOccurred) event to get notified of network errors. The `error` property will contain the network error code.

For example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.error == 'net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE') {
        console.log('Insecure request detected', details);
    }
}, {
    urls: ['*://*/*'],
    types: ['xmlhttprequest']
});
var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
x.open('get','https://example.com');
x.send();
```

If for testing only, just start Chrome with the `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag to allow self-signed certificates to be used. This affects all websites in the same browsing session, so I suggest to use a separate profile directory for this purpose, by appending `--user-data-dir=/tmp/temporaryprofiledirectory` to the command line arguments.

Another way to avoid the error in the first place is to get a valid SSL certificate. For non-commericial purposes, you can get a [free SSL certificate](https://www.startssl.com/?app=1) at https://www.startssl.com.

Comment: With StartCom (responsible for StartSSL) and WoSign (responsible for StartCom) being under scrutiny and [essentially unable to sign new certs](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3137162/security/google-to-untrust-wosign-and-startcom-certificates.html), the main and possibly only free alternative is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: I use Let's Encrypt but I still get net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE. I'm implementing oauth2 and one https redirects to another after authentication, and I get that error in the console. However, in the address bar, it says secure https and there are no errors whatsoever.