# how to handle net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ssl-certificate, general-network-error

I get the **net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE** when making an ajax call to https url.
When i open that https url once in the browser and accept the certificate, i do not get that error.
but i do not want to open that url in the browser and want my javascript catch the error **net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**.

I found one link (i.e. [How to handle ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498821/how-to-handle-err-insecure-response-in-google-chrome-extension)) which actually not working.

Appreciate a lot if someone guide me in the right direction in how to handle this error programmatically. Did all possible searches in google with no luck.

Comment: the solution you linked should work.  post your code.

Comment: @Thouartamazing When I used chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred, it's says can't call onErrorOccurred on undefined. Do I need to add some chrome specific js file for that.

Comment: Are you trying to use this from a Content Script ?

Comment: did you add the right permission

Comment: @Thouartamazing i do not know how to add permission. I just used the mentioned api and it does not work. Can you please tell me the step to do before running the code chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred. I mean how and where to add permissions.

Comment: read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions and add "permissions": [
  "webRequest"
] to your manifest

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a Content Script. But Content script can't use all chrome API.

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> 1. Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
>    - extension (getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest)
>    - i18n
>    - runtime (connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage)
>    - storage
> 2. Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> 3. Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

So you can't use `chrome.webRequest` API in content script. `chrome.webReqest` is undefined like all other chrome API except the 4 previously listed.

[More information in Chrome Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)