# How to ignore ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error in javaScript or php

Tags: javascript, php, apache, splunk

I am working with web application (*PHP* and *javaScript*) , and i am using *splunk javaScript sdk* to connect to *splunk*.

But while making `API` call, i am getting "**ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**" error in console.

Is there any way to ignore this error (using any script or *splunk conf* file)?

I am using apache as server.

Thanks!

Comment: You may consider checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24499090/6381711); it might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using https as a protocol, then unless you have proper certificates deployed to your server that are recognized by your browser, you have to load URL to your back-end resource in the browser bar and accept the exception. Then browser should allow the communication till the permission is expired.

On the production you have to deploy proper certificates for the browsers to allow the communication w/o prompting to the user.

Btw, here is similar topic:
[Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response)

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks
Is there any way to accept the connection in back-end, as i don't want user to accept it manually. I want script to accept the connection automatically without asking the user about this.

Comment: It is a security feature of the browser, script cannot override it (for good reasons - you don't want users data to be hijacked). Only way to go around it in production is to get and deploy trusted certificates to your server.